# Probability a random walk hits zero at specified time set

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $X_n \in \lbrace -1, 0, 1 \rbrace$ be sequence of i.i.d random variables taking $-1$ or $1$ with equal probability, and $0$ some positive probability. $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i$ is a random walk. It is easy to see that $S_n$ is null recurrent. Let Q be the set of indexes so that $S_n = 0$, namely the set of return to zero times. Let $W \subset \mathbb{N}$ be any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Is it true or false that 
\begin{align*} Pr[W \cap Q = \emptyset] = 0 \end{align*}

Comment: Informally we are asking if we can construct an adversarial infinite index set so that  probability of random walk hitting zero during these indexes is not an almost sure event

Comment: Let $W=\{w_k\mid k\in\mathbb N\}$ with $w_{k}<w_{k+1}$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. The transition probabilities of $X$ are such that $P(X_n=y\mid X_0=x)\leqslant c/\sqrt{n}$ for every $(n,x,y)$, hence $$P(W\cap Q=\varnothing)\geqslant\prod_{k\in\mathbb N}\left(1-\frac{c}{\sqrt{w_{k+1}-w_{k}}}\right).$$ If $W$ is sparse enough, say $w_k\sim k^{3+\varepsilon}$ with $\varepsilon>0$, the RHS is positive. On the other hand, if $w_k=k$, then $P(W\cap Q=\varnothing)=0$ since $X$ is recurrent.